# Django/Python - How to show "task" ONLY if the user is author or responsable of "task"

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python and django and I need some help, please.

What I'm trying to do is to only show a certain "task" if the user is responsable or author of the "task" in question.

I was trying to do that with a if statement in html template:

```
    {% for task in task_list %}
    <h2>title - {{task.title}}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```

But does not return what I expected since:

```
    {% for task in task_list %}
    <h2>author --- {{task.author}}</h2>
    <h2>responsable --- {{task.responsable}}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
```

Returns me the same user... I think the problem is that when I refer user.username it goes to the db and returns a query, and when I user {{task.blablabla}} its a string, I'm right? How I can fix that?

models.py:

```
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=User)
    responsable = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="author", default=User)
    STATUS_CHOICES = [('D', 'Done'),('P','Doing'),('N','Not done')]
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='N')
    IMPORTANCE_CHOICES = [('H', 'High'),('M','Medium'),('L','Low')]
    importance = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=IMPORTANCE_CHOICES, default='M')
    DEPARTAMENT_CHOICES = [('D', 'Dev'),('M','Marketing'),('H','Human Resources'),('L','Legal'),('F','Financial'),('O','Others')]
    departament = models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=DEPARTAMENT_CHOICES, default='M')

    def  __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def dashboard_taskapp(request):
    task = Task.objects.all()
    context = {
        "task_list": task,
    }
    return render(request, "task_app/task_dashboard.html", context)
```

Thanks in advance and kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the cleaner and safer solution here is to use [Class Based Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/) (CBV). There is a generic CBV specially created for displaying lists of objects - [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview). To achieve exactly what you did the code would present as follows:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class DashboardTaskAppView(ListView):
    
    template_name = "task_app/task_dashboard.html"
    
    # we override this method to 
    # get the queryset of objects we want to display
    # rest of the work will be taken care of by "djnago"
    def get_queryset(self):
        usr = request.user
        return Task.objects.filter(Q(author=usr) | Q(responsible=usr) | Q(public=True))
```

Now to get the wanted result in template we simply invoke it like this

```
    {% for task in object_list %}
       <h2>title - {{task.title}}</h2>
    {% endfor %}
```

when using CBV remember to user path in urls like this

```
path('your_url/', DashboardTaskAppView.as_view(), name='your_name'),
```

Please read the docs to discover full Django generic views potential it really speeds up your job and reformatting it later on takes seconds instead of hours.

Comment: edit: Q(public=True) will add all the public posts to diplayed queryset so I hope it solved your problem. I don't know your database stats concerning number of tasks and users so I suggested the simplest to understand solution with straight forward filtering

Comment: Your solution is MUCH better than the one I had! Thank you for share your knowledge, from now on I'll always try to implement class view when is a better fit. I just started and I have to say, thank you for your time and patience! It's awesome to know I'm trying to learn to be like you guys. Thanks @quqa123

Comment: Edit: here I hade to call the request user with "self"
`usr = self.request.user`

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you want to achieve. Firstly, modify `task` queryset so it only shows your chosen person's tasks. (You need to import Q for OR contidion)

```
from django.db.models import Q

def dashboard_taskapp(request):
    usr = request.user
    task = Task.objects.filter(Q(author=usr) | Q(responsible=usr))
    context = {
        "task_list": task,
    }
    return render(request, "task_app/task_dashboard.html", context)
```

Then there is no need to limit your template so in the end it will look like this

```
    {% for task in task_list %}
    <h2>title - {{task.title}}</h2>
    ... whatever you wanna show here ...
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: There exists a better, more clean solution if you're willing to use class based views - just ask. and btw u mentioned using `if` statement in your template but there is only `{% endif %}` visible

Comment: Yesss! I'm willing to use the cleanest solution, I'll look into class based views. Your solution with the Q from db is perfect! Thank you. I was trying to do with `if` statement because I also want to create a Boolean field in models.py "is public" and if is "True" show to all users. Thanks again @quqa123!

Comment: It's possible do what I want with the boolean value?
and about the `{% endif %}` I made a mistake when I pasted! Sorry and many thanks

Comment: well if I understand you correctly there is something like "my tasks" dashboard where user can see his tasks along with the public tasks that are ment to be shown in every users dashboard?